# В каком случае "федеральный" пишется с большой буквы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, заглавная

Скажите, пожалуйста, в сочетании "вас приветствует федеральная сеть частных детских садов" слово "федеральный" пишется с большой или маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 2):

Выбор прописной или строчной буквы зависит от того, является  ли сочетание «федеральная сеть частных детских садов» **именем собственными** или нет.

Приведем  примеры.

1. Существует такое понятие, как **организационно-правовая форма предприятий**, например: Вид учреждения: детский сад. Организационно-правовая форма: муниципальное бюджетное дошкольное учреждение. Тогда общее официальное название имеет вид:  Муниципальное бюджетное дошкольное образовательное учреждение «Детский сад № 1»
2. Сравним: **Федеральная сеть детских садов  Art Favmily** или Федеральная сеть детских садов «Детская страна».  Если понятие «федеральная сеть детских садов» имеет официальный статус, то есть является организационно-правовой формой со своим уставом, то слово «федеральная»  пишется с прописной буквы (как первое слово имени собственного в официальном названии).

Если такого статуса нет, то это будет нарицательное наименование, и оно должно писаться со строчной буквы.

3. Возможно, это сочетание не относится к правовой сфере, а является названием какой-то **общественной организации или канала радиовещания**. В этом случае это также имя собственное, которое пишется с прописной буквы.

Answer (score 1):

Слово федеральный в названиях округов пишется с маленькой буквы: Северо-Западный федеральный округ, Южный федеральный округ  и др. С большой буквы федеральный пишется как первое слово официального названия: Федеральная служба безопасности РФ, Федеральное агентство по печати и массовым коммуникациям и т. п.